# "Make a pass at someone" Vs "Hit on someone"

Tags: idioms, expressions

I would appreciate it if someone could let me know what is the usual AE idiom which is used when someone is going to sweet talk to a female in order to persuade her to making friends and starting a (usually sexual) relationship?

I know two idioms that according to the dictionary definitions seem to be identical; however I have my doubts:

a) [make a pass at someone:](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/make-a-pass-at-someone) 
to try **to start a sexual relationship** with someone, for example by **talking to them** or touching them in a sexual way 
b) [hit on someone:](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/hit-on) 
to **talk to someone** in a way that shows you are **sexually attracted** to them.

> - I'm tired of complete strangers ......... me when I go out.

1. making a pass at:
2. hitting on

Although they mean the same to me, but I think "make a pass" is somehow an old-fashioned or even obsolete idiom in my preferred language which is modern AE.
Please let me know about it.

Comment: You are correct that both phrases generally refer to a male attempting to get a female interested in him sexually. You are also correct that “make a pass” is an older term than “hit on.” It may also be correct that “make a pass” was less forceful in its implications that “hit on.”

Comment: Make a pass at isn't obsolete, but it is dated.